# Does MongoDB Atlas support Drill down capability?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, drillthrough

Using MongoDB Atlas for our HR Analytics product, but can't drill down into data. E.g. Attrition analytics -> Go by Location -> drill down into Grade/Band -> Gender, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Atlas is MongoDB's Database as a Service offering. It's not an analytics tool, however, you can leverage your MongoDB databases in Atlas for analytics in one or more of several ways:

- https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/bi-connection/  The BI Connector in Atlas gives you the ability to connect traditional BI Analytics tools like Qlik, Tableau to your MongoDB data directly.
- https://docs.mongodb.com/charts/master/launch-charts/ - Charts lets you drill into and create analytical charts directly from the data in your Atlas databases.

Hope this helps.